# Uploading to the KDE store?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, themes, repository

I was working on a custom theme for KDE and decided to make a commit on [open code](https://www.opencode.net) so I could add the theme to the [KDE store](https://store.kde.org/browse/cat/) for easy downloading, reinstalling and sharing via the KDE interface.

All was going well, the commit to open code went fine but now I am at a loose end as I can't see how to go from there to adding my theme to the store repos.

Can anyone outline the steps required to add a theme to the KDE store?

Perhaps I am just being dumb but I couldn't find anything on this.

I understand that this won't be as simple as clicking a button but some kind of documentation to get me started would be a great help.